# RichTextBox для WPF шустрее, чем родной?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

В окне отображаю лог довольно длительного процесса (5000 операций в среднем по 10 строчек каждая, потом будет и больше вплоть до 500k строчек)

Как известно, plain text убог :) например, на MacOS в стандартном блокноте только rich text.
вот и у меня для удобства чтения и для красоты часть строчек имеет свой цвет, часть кусков текста выделяется желтым маркером, возможно даже будут ссылки или и того круче - спойлеры из UIElement.

Но после того, как строк накопится много, лог тормозит и на выделение его кусков мышью (причем кусков совсем маленьких) и - что самое неприятное - на само добавление строк.

Есть ли что-то шустрее?

Решил попробовать три варианта - Syncfusion, Telerik и ComponentOne - и замерить. **И ни один не заработал вообще**.
Видно, не мой день.
(С первым разобрался, сделал все по аналогии с оригиналом, все работает, но строки добавленной не видно.
Второй вылетает при простом добавлении самого rtb в пустое окно свежесозданного проекта точь-в-точь по мануалу Getting started.
Со третьим разобрался, сделал все по аналогии с оригиналом, все работает, но строки добавленной не видно.
Пишу в саппорты...)

**Единственным заработал AvalonEdit**, но он заточен под подсветку синтаксиса, и я не понял, как в нем просто взять и задать шрифт для такого-то участка. И примитивный он какой-то по виду.

Интересно имеет ли вообще смысл что-то искать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66064/discussion-on-question-by-koshkashoshka-richtextbox--wpf---).

Answer (score 6):

Вы не должны держать в памяти громадные массивы UI-контролов. Это неправильно и не нужно. Для отображения логов прекрасно подходит виртуализированный список. А для отображения — легковесный `TextBlock`. Я обойдусь стоковыми средствами.

Дополнительные преимущества списка — вы легко можете устроить фильтрацию, сортировку и прочие плюшки, чего не так-то просто добиться в чисто текстовом формате.

Давайте засучим рукава и напишем немного кода.

Создадим простейший класс для одного элемента лога.

```
class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime Time { get; }
    public int Severity { get; }
    public string ModuleName { get; }
    public string Text { get; }

    public LogEntry(DateTime time, int severity, string moduleName, string text)
    {
        Time = time;
        Severity = severity;
        ModuleName = moduleName;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Создадим 500K таких элементов, и положим их список в `DataContext`. Отображение — в XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:SeverityConverter x:Key="SevConv"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Background="{Binding Severity, Converter={StaticResource SevConv}}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Я использую самописный конвертер Severity в цвет:

```
class SeverityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        switch ((int)value)
        {
        case 1: return Brushes.Red;
        case 2: return Brushes.Yellow;
        case 3: return Brushes.Green;
        default: return Brushes.Black;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Да, давайте создадим случайные данные.

```
static class LogEntryFactory
{
    static Random r = new Random();
    static string[] Modules = { "Main", "VM", "Model", "DataBase", "Connectivity" };

    public static LogEntry CreateRandom()
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(r.NextDouble() * 10);
        var severity = r.Next(1, 4);
        var moduleName = Modules[r.Next(Modules.Length)];
        var text = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(0, r.Next(2, 10))
                                              .Select(_ => CreateRandomWord()));
        return new LogEntry(time, severity, moduleName, text);
    }

    static char[] allowedChars = Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Select(Convert.ToChar)
                         .Concat(Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(Convert.ToChar)).ToArray();

    private static string CreateRandomWord() =>
        new string(Enumerable.Range(0, r.Next(3, 12))
                             .Select(_ => allowedChars[r.Next(allowedChars.Length)])
                             .ToArray());
}
```

Запускаем. Выводим надпись «Creating» на время создания в фоновом потоке 500K элементов.

[image: ну довольно быстро, да]

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы можно было выделять текст, придётся использовать `RichTextBox` в каждой строке. Получается как-то так:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:SeverityConverter x:Key="SevConv"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
            <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Background="{Binding Severity,
                                                  Converter={StaticResource SevConv}}"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Получается так:

[image: ну тоже ничё вроде]

Выделять текст через границу ячеек нельзя, можно только в одной.

---

Дополнение. Наверняка вы хотите выделять не внутри одной строки, а несколько строк, используя Ctrl-C и контекстное меню. Это тоже можно сделать, мы ж программисты!

Возвращаемся к `TextBlock`'ам, добавляем Multiselect, привязку команды `ApplicationCommands.Copy` и контекстное меню:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:SeverityConverter x:Key="SevConv"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="OnListCopy"/>
    </ListView.CommandBindings>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ModuleName, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Background="{Binding Severity, Converter={StaticResource SevConv}}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

В code-behind:

```
void OnListCopy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var lv = (ListView)sender;
    var text = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            lv.SelectedItems.Cast<LogEntry>().OrderBy(entry => entry.Time));
    Clipboard.SetText(text);
}
```

(Зачем понадобилось `OrderBy`? Дело в том, что `ListView` сортирует `SelectedItems` в порядке выделения, а не в порядке, в котором они показываются в списке. Тривиального метода обойти это нет, но в нашем случае мы можем просто отсортировать по времени, это же лог. Спасибо @tym32167 за подсказку!)

В `LogEntry` добавляем

```
public override string ToString() => $"{Time} {ModuleName} {Text}";
```

Пробуем:

[image: ну, чего вам ещё надо?]

Comment: Мне когда то такое не подошло, так как нельзя было просто взять и скопировать текст отсюда

Comment: @tym32167: тогда либо деактивировать `RichTextBox` и использовать (но всё равно внутри `ItemsControl`'а), либо обработчик на клик.

Comment: А разве оно позволит мне выделить сразу несколько элементов, как внутри обычного текстбокса, если использовать ItemsControl? Чтобы было понятно, я мне нужна была замена контрола для чата отсюда https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/master/desc/7.PNG

Comment: @tym32167: Вы имеете в виду выделение через границы Item'а? Нет, такого нет. Но это и понятно: чтобы такое сделать, нужно и вправду держать в памяти все элементы (что если вы выделили _весь_ текст?)

Comment: да, это и имею ввиду. Потому и переключился тогда на текстбокс от винфонм. Он пошустрее был.

Comment: @tym32167: С копированием разобрался, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @VladD если у вас вдохновение и время есть, то может стоит в gist это дело постануть, а то и в репо? будете сидеть пилить. но если это для меня, то даже смотреть не буду такой вариант. отказаться от RTB в пользу менее гибкого ListBox, а потом героически реализовывать все поведение RTB - изврат... лучше напишите RTB с бесконечным скроллом сверху и снизу, а хранил бы он подгруженную часть часть в RTB, а остальное просто во FlowDocument-ах, т.е. все в памяти, потом придумаем как излишек как на диске хранить как опцию, если уж у кого-то не найдется свободных 500-2000 МБ ОЗУ.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Подумайте, как вы в RTB-формате сделаете, например, такую фишку как «показать сообщения за последний час с Severity = Critical». Подумайте, как в `ListBox`'е. Думаю, вы поймёте, что RTB — это костыль.

Comment: @VladD Рядом с RTB сделать TextBlock: 7 ошибок. кликаем по нему, открывается попап с гиперссылками на те места, где ошибки. обновляться этот список и TextBlock будет при добавлении сообщений в лог, это не поиск и не фильтр, так что переход к ошибке работать будет моментально

Comment: @koshkashoshka: На SO код намного полезнее :) В гист никто не заглянет, а на SO люди придут (да или меня самого гугл приведёт).

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Окей, а теперь этих ошибок не 7, а 70000, наши действия? Кликаем по каждой? Или лучше фильтрация? Да, а как вы собираетесь делать переход на позицию в RTB? Каким образом можно пометить эту позицию?

Comment: @VladD Каждая гиперссылка хранит текст ошибки. Над списком гиперссылок добавляем поле поиск. Что лучше - искать ошибку в  ошибках или искать по всему логу? А гиперссылку уж как-нибудь сделаю, получить строку при добавлении проблем нет, как и прокрутить до нее.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Поле поиска — это уже интереснее. А как мы будем искать, ведь в попапе 70К строк. Что используем — ListBox или снова RTB?

Comment: @VladD ну 70К в попапе лучше, чем 1КК в логе

Comment: Очень полезный пример, спасибо. Единственно что хочу отметить - элементы в ```lv.SelectedItems``` могут находиться в порядке, отличном от исходной коллекции, то есть их желательно сортировать перед записью в текст где то тут ```var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lv.SelectedItems.Cast<LogEntry>());```

Comment: @tym32167: Не знал этого факта, спасибо! Дополнил ответ.