# WPF Grid TextBox с выделением

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Как взять из DataGrid только

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е сами строки без header'a и т.д но чтобы можно было выделять и т.д

Comment: Переопределите шаблон для заголовков

Comment: [это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710061/179763)

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread514650.html Посмотрите, пожалуйста