# Как добавить виртуализацию в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, виртуализация, richtextbox

Использую `WinForms`. Мне нужно выводить много информации в `RichTextBox`, но со временем он наполняется большим кол-вом информации и, как следствие, обновление текста в нем через `Append` занимает больше времени, чем в пустом.

Вопрсо: как можно реализовать виртуализацию в нем?

Интересуют следующие моменты:

1. Заставить ползунок отображать больше информации, чем в него
   фактически загружено. Например, находимся мы в конце и выгрузили 90%
   текста, но нужно визуально дать понять, что текст в верху есть.
2. Ловить момент, когда нужно загрузить следующую порцию данных и
   выгрузить часть данных.

Готовые реализации в виде каких-то отдельных библиотек меня не интересуют, хочется понять сам принцип создания контрола с виртуализацией с 0.

Comment: скорее всего никак

Comment: поглядите на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710061/179763) вариант

Comment: @tym32167, даже через наследование? По идее, события листания есть и этим можно пользоваться. Другой вопрос- это ползунок, который должен создавать впечатление, что загружено много.

Comment: насколько я помню, rtb поддерживает и разные размеры шрифтов, и разбивку длинных строк автоматом. Потому, если, например, юзер проскроллил 30% вашего текстбокса, вы никак не поймете, что именно надо отрисовать. Виртуализация - это для контролов, которые состоят из строк одинаковой высоты, чтобы можно было понять, какие строки при каких скроллах отрисовывать.

Comment: @tym32167, теоретически, это не такая уж и большая проблема. Можно хранить где-то List<string>, где каждый элемент- это 1 страница=> текст можно отображать блоками. В зависимости от размера шрифта можно как-то хитро вычислять размер и этим контроллировать наполнение "страниц". Т.е одна буквы 90pt будет ровняться 1 странице.

Comment: и это будет работать до тех пор, пока не включится перенос слов. К тому же, если вы собираетесь хранить список строк, то зачем вам вообще текстбокс? Храните так, как делают по ссылке, что я привел выше - у меня в моей проге чат аналогично устроен, с виртуализацией, и все пашет отлично

Comment: @tym32167, у тебя там wpf.

Comment: @Qwertiy а, блин, точно, забыл, что тут про винформс :)

Comment: [ссылка](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=827198&msg=10205291)