# Вывод большого количества срок в RichTextBox на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Написал небольшое приложения которое читает логи по SHH с разных серверов. 
Сейчас все работает на WinForms, но я хотел бы перенести на WPF.
Сейчас библиотека, работающая с SSH, в цикле выдает мне строки, а я их 
**RichTextBox.Appendtext(строчкаизлога);**

В вывод часто попадет много строк, более 1000. По ходу вывода необходимо эти строки форматировать(подсвечивать определенный синтаксис).

Подскажите как правильно организовать архитектуру приложения учитывая все современные паттерны WPF. Я ведь так понимаю что мне нужно создать какой-то объект и забиндить его к WPF-компоненту Rixhtextbox. Сам richtextbox **readonly**. Мне именно нужно понять как правильно создать объект в памяти, как работать с ним(добавлять строки, очищать), как все это должно выводиться в RichTextBox и подсвечивался синтаксис(желательно по RegExp). После того как мы получили все строки из лога нужна возможность уже в самом приложении отфильтровать строки.

Comment: _подсвечивать синтаксис_ - рекомендую для этой цели взять готовый компонент. Например, [ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET) или [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox). Оба WinForms. Думаю, вам подскажут для WPF. Реализовывать это с нуля такое себе занятие...

Comment: RichTextBox не предназначен для большого количества текста. Я бы вам посоветовал для этого иcпользовать контрол с виртуализацией, например [список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710061/179763). Я как то решал подобную проблему ([чат](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/master/desc/2.PNG)), у меня получилось [следующее](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.ChatModule/Boxes/ColoredItemsControl.xaml).

Comment: Попробовал использовать fastColoredTextBox. Выводит строки достаточно медленно. Мне нужно чтобы они сразу вылетали как в SHH клиентах, например PUTTY.
Использую код:
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                            { 
                                fastColoredTextBox.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
                                fastColoredTextBox.GoEnd();
                            }
                            Application.DoEvents();